# Subject and verb in subordinate clauses

Tags: conjunctions, subordinate-clauses, parallelism

I'm wondering: is it necessary to repeat the subject - or the verb - of a sentence in subordinate clauses introduced by words such as "but" or "like"? Are the following sentences equally correct?

> a) Flight attendants share 22 things they'd love to tell passengers but can't.
>
> b) Elizabeth Warren is the US president we need, but can’t have.
>
> c) We thought she'd know the answer to this question, but she didn't.
>
> d) She thinks I'm jealous, but - surprise, surprise! - I'm not.
>
> e) Over time people started to get older, things didn't pan out like they were supposed to.
>
> f) As much as I used to, nowadays I don't go to gigs that often.

Comment: You are correct. _Ellipses_ like the one in _"Flight attendants share 22 things they'd love to tell passengers but can't (tell them)"_ are common in idiomatic English.

Comment: Something is missing in (e); should it be “Over time, as people started”?

Comment: Interestingly, (b) is the only one in which I'd accept adding or removing the subject of the last verb.  It's hard to articulate why I would not tolerate a second _they_ in (a).  In (c,d) the implied subject would be that of the main clause, clearly wrong.

Comment: f) is unidiomatic because of the pleonasm: "as much as I used to....that often".  Nowadays I don't go to gigs that often.   Nowadays I don't go to gigs as much as I used to.

Comment: c) is a cuckoo in the nest.   It doesn't follow the pattern since the subject is "We" not "she".  The first "she" heads a content clause, complement of "thought".

Answer (score 1):

Item (e) contains a comma splice, which is generally (but not universally) considered incorrect. It could be removed by adding "as":

*Over time, **as** people started to get older, things didn't pan out like they were supposed to.*

Item (f) sounds a little odd. In contrast to the previous case, I would fix it by **removing** "as":

*Much as I used to, nowadays I don't go to gigs that often.*

The other sentences are all fine.